# API web data capture

Tags: python, api, web-scraping

I am attempting to pull golf stats for an analysis project.

TL;DR summary:
Should I scrape or use a loop with API I found in network console?

I want to pull data for 6 or 7 stat categories, by year(2015-present), and preferably by tournament to better categorize player tournament performance.
Base Url is: `https://www.pgatour.com/stats`

The site has numerous pages, and once you click on the specific stat page it has three drop down fields:
Season (contains year), Time Period(Tournament Only or YTD), and Tournament(Name of Tournament)

Found possible hidden API:

```
https://statdata-api-prod.pgatour.com/api/clientfile/YTDEventStats?T_CODE=r&STAT_ID=02671&YEAR=2021&format=json
```

But this only has data for the most recent tournament and it's not very clean (no stat category titles for table data):

I can make adjustment to the JSON API, by changing the Stat ID=value and also the the year. So this is in an option, but I would have to figure out how to add the tournament id number and tournament stats only as key value pairs.

URL for an example looks like this: `https://www.pgatour.com/content/pgatour/stats/stat.02674.y2017.eon.t030.html`
eon makes the stats tournament only (eoff is for YTD) and t030 is the tournament marker.

Should I just create loops and change the year, tournament number and stat number and get all info in JSON and try to get it into a df?

1. How would I add the tournament and eon qualifiers as key-value pairs in JSON url?
2. Is this even feasible?

Or should I scrape it instead and try to use the HTML (would be able to capture stat row headers, possibly)?

Included snapshot of one table from the website

[image: PGA table snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for scraping, as the url itself gives you more control over what you're after. Also, you can easily get the tabular data with pandas.

For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


headers = {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.99 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

url = "https://www.pgatour.com/content/pgatour/stats/stat.02674.y2017.eon.t030.html"
html = requests.get(url).text

df = pd.read_html(html, flavor="html5lib")
df = pd.concat(df).drop([0, 1, 2], axis=1)
df.to_csv("golf.csv", index=False)
```

Gives you this:

[image]

You can then keep swapping the urls or modify the `stat.`, `y`, and `eon` part of the URL to get different stats. For example, this is 2018 U.S. Open - https://www.pgatour.com/content/pgatour/stats/stat.02674.y2017.eon.t030.html

Comment: Thanks. Would I need to rotate headers if I am looping through multiple years and tournament pages?

Comment: Your picture is great

Comment: No need to rotate headers. And thanks for the complement about the picture. ;)